# Running R inside a buffer in Vim

Tags: vim, plugins, shell, r

I have used Stata and gVim on Windows for a while now. Recently I have switched to Linux, and I am planning to also change from Stata to R.

A friend of mine is using R and Emacs ESS which seems to work perfect, however i'd rather like to keep using vim. I have installed the vim-r-plugin2, however, i can only send code to a seperate terminal running R. I would much rather split my screen into a buffer running R and one buffer with my .R file, and then send code from one to the other. With ESS in Emacs this seems to work, you can run a terminal/R in a buffer without a problem. I haven't found a way to make this work. The R plugin for vim uses screen, and the only way to open a buffer running a shell I could find is the Conque Shell plugin.

I know that unlike Emacs, Vim is designed to be a simple text editor. However, having R run in a buffer seems just so much more practical.

I hope my problem is understandable, please bear with me I only recently switched to Linux and know virtually nothing about programming besides statistics. Thanks!

Comment: I use Vim and vim-r-plugin2 in both OSX and Ubuntu and wrestled with the same thing, but now I'm really happy with Vim for editing and Terminal for executing. In the Terminal all I really need is tab-completion, which is where Vim falls a little short I think.

Comment: I used to do everything in gedit + rgedit, but I learned that switching to a more powerful GUI was worth the effort. I use Eclipse, which is pretty similar in function to ESS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not need to input unicode, you can consider using [ConqueShell plugin](http://conque.googlecode.com/).

Comment: I know about the ConqueShell plugin. But how do I get the vim-r-plugin to work with it?

Comment: @ilprincipe It cannot work with ConqueShell out-of-the box, but you can try to use my fork of this plugin: http://github.com/ZyX-I/vim-r-plugin2: it adds initial ConqueShell support, in order to use it set `g:vimrplugin_conqueplugin` in your vimrc. Maybe this changes will be pulled by the author later.

Comment: ive tried your solution, it works partly, some of the keybindings dont work since conqueshell can only send selections to a shell, not strings. ive shared your files with the author here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9836800#post9836800

Comment: @ilprincipe It can send strings to shell, review my solution. But this is undocumented and so may be changed in future versions without notice (though I do not think that this is likely).

Comment: @ilprincipe By the way, my commit was pulled into base repository. I do not know, whether package was updated, if not you can use [vim-addon-manager](http://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-manager) to install it from Git (you will need git installed). Add `call scriptmanager#Activate("Vim-R-plugin2")` to your vimrc and answer `y<CR>` on all queries at startup (one `y` and one `<CR>`, ignoring the fact that it will 'repeat' prompt after you press `y`).

Comment: I installed Vim-R-Plugin (version from 2011-01-17); once I installed conque plugin, it was used by default.

Comment: the vim-r-plugin2 is about 2yrs old now, and there have been quite a few updates to the Vim-R-plugin that is its [basis](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628) - is there still a reason to prefer vim-r-plugin2?

Comment: @ricardo Better to ask on the IRC or vim-use mailing list. I currently use neither (and my advice is almost two years old as well).

Answer (score 2):

In the meanwhile, the 'evil' (extensible vi emulation layer) mode has matured. This is a vim emulator running in Emacs and works quite well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, and forgive me for pointing you back to EMACS,

viper-mode

http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/RZ/software/emacs/viper/viper_3.html

It's an EMACS mode that makes EMACS feel more like Vim, while giving you full access to the wonderful, mind-boggling complexity of EMACS if you ever want it.

Comment: thanks, I know about viper mode, but if I'm using emacs, I'm using emacs and not a hybrid. however, I'd rather continue to use vim.